# Do initialization of any variable invokes GC in JAVA

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have got a Java memory puzzle from internet and trying hard to understand it, and what I understood till now is that Java is releasing memory of object with ended life on initialization of new object, though I am unable to get any proof on the same. If any one have any idea on it please guide.

Puzzle is as below

```
private final int dataSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() * 0.6);

public void f()
{
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
    }
    //int i = 0; //If uncommented then program work fine
    byte[] data2 = new byte[dataSize];

}
```

Comment: The problem you have is that you don't know when the JVM will make the variable free. It is much better to write a program which doesn't rely on this behaviour. (and to manage the life cycle of really large buffers yourself, if not make them off heap)

Comment: It is not my problem , I just wanted to know whether on any object creation gc is invoked or not.If yes how ?

Comment: A GC is triggered whenever the JVM cannot create an object because there is not enough memory. It can also be triggered at other times depending on what GC you have.

Comment: But in this case it is not happening when I am trying to create data2 object it is throwing error of OutOfMemory

Comment: This is because the previous `data` local variable is not being discarded. You can't be sure this will happen unless you return from a method. It might happen when it goes out of scope, but it might not.

Comment: And How it always run if I initiate a int i before data2

Comment: Local variables get reused, and if you add an `int i` it happens to reuse the same location as `data` thus clearing it. Why it does do this for `data2` is unclear and most likely implementation dependant.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to understand that why it hasn't done this for data2 and doing this for int i

Comment: You could look at the byte code with `javap -c -v` to get a clue, however if this doesn't help you would need to read the JVM source.

Comment: tried checking bytecode but got no clue

Comment: any idea on checking jvm source for that

Comment: You can download the source from here http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/